# Does IHP run migrations atomically?

Tags: ihp

I can't seem to find this in the guide. Is it necessary for us to add `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` to our migration files or is this handled by IHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IHP does implicitly wrap the migrations within a transaction. So you don't need to wrap your migrations between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`. To disable this implicit wrapping you wrap your migration between `COMMIT` and `BEGIN` (the other way round). You can read more about it [here](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/database-migrations.html).

Comment: Oh, missed that in the guide, thank you!